# Resources to learn QML?

Tags: qt, qml

Can you please suggest resources to learn QML ( Qt Markup Language )?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068954/qt5-0-2-qml-qtquick2-0-c-example-projects-that-run-without-errors/16069932#16069932

Comment: Qt5 Cadaques: https://qmlbook.github.io/#

Comment: you can find a collection of the best qml tutorials here:
https://v-play.net/qt/qt-tutorials-resources-for-beginners

Comment: I am trying to learn QT and QML by altering/editing a very complex ICS program and it is hell on Earth... so what ever you do, dont do it this way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can find valuable informations on following [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-tutorial.html).
There, beside tutorial you can find a list of QML elements as well as examples and demos.

Comment: Demos are here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeexamples.html  List of elements are here: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativeelements.html

Answer (score 22):

This is an old question but if someone still is wondering the same question, I'll answer this as an update for the previous answer.

The tutorials described in the URL above are still valid, very comprehensive and useful, and there are now also developer guides for mobile and desktop QML development at link: http://www.qt.io/training-materials/. The guides there are very beginner-friendly step-by-step tutorials with clear and comprehensive explanations, so don't hesitate to check these out too.

EDIT 11.7.2012: There is also now a very nice set of Qt Quick tutorials available in the following address: [http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtquick.html](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtquick.html). So if you're interested in Qt and QML, go check those out!

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest others very usefull guides written by Digia. Those guides cover several topics like design strategies for modern application design, instruduction to Qt Quick, OpenGL, Qt Effects, game development and use of canvas.

Have a look at this link: [http://download.qt.io/learning/developerguides/](http://download.qt-project.org/learning/developerguides/)