# Qt, QML and Windows 8

Tags: qt, windows-8, qml

I always been curious about QML introduced by Qt framework. But never had a chance to work with it. But now with Windows 8 coming, old school widget based interface is going to get outdated (just my opinion! :) ). Now I want to ask those, who had some experience with QML: Is it easy to write Metro-style (or how is it called nowadays) applications with QML? Is the QML photoshop plugin useable for real project?

For those who don't have a clue about Photoshop plugin, try search in youtube: Introducing Qt Quick for Stunning UI Creation - Nokia Developer Day, Barcelona 2011 (not sure, whether I can post links here :P)

Also, Is there any good Windows applications I can look, written in QML?

Comment: Read this if you already have not: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-on-Windows-8-and-Metro-UI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`is there any good Windows applications I can look, written in QML?`

Go through the [trending Qml repositories at GitHub](https://github.com/trending/qml) to get a good idea. People are implementing [material design](https://github.com/papyros/qml-material) ideas in QML as well. Correct me if am wrong but lot of [Sailfish's](https://sailfishos.org/design/ux-framework/) UI was done in QML as well. Infact, the SDK for the OS is based on Qt/QML.

I am personally fond of [GCompris](http://gcompris.net/index-en.html). They moved from GTK to QML and have been able to run their code on several platforms including Windows/Android/OSX etc.

`is it easy to write Metro-style applications with QML?`

I would personally say that qml is very capable of developing the fluid 'metro like' UIs in a very intuitive and easy way.

You can go through the links given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347469/resources-to-learn-qml) to get started on QML.

You can start with the [Qt Wiki](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt-5-on-Windows-8-and-Metro-UI) on it, and go through [how to create Metro style applications](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2012/01/25/how-to-create-qt-applications-with-metro-style-2/) and read about [deploying on Windows 8](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/11/24/deploying-on-windows-8-tablets-with-qt-commercial-2/).

`Is the QML photoshop plugin useable for real project?`

I havent used the Photoshop one, but the one for [GIMP](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/gimp-qmlexporter) (YES! is exists for GIMP as well, man open source developers do some nice work!!!). Although it might not be very intuitive in its approach to generate files, but it still is a very nice tool to work on single files (screens), when your UI is not expected to change at all.

It gives hard coded values to pixels ( eg: width : 45 ) instead of writing it in a dependent way ( eg. parent.width * .75 ), thus in case there are modifications in UI you might end up modifying a lot.

And personally I would say qml is just awesome to learn and have fun.

And thanks hyde for that link.

---

Edit:

Also go through these:

1. [A video showing the Metro like effects, written in qml](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTEMkDZxpaw)
2. [A video showing the IVI capability of qml](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXDK5orGuFU). Just so that you can get an idea of what qml might be capable in terms of animations etc.

Comment: It looks like the links have mostly gone dead.

Comment: @XTL Updated the links and added some more relevant information. Guess thats why SO suggests so strongly against link only answers.